# Can I set Javascript object keys based on a variable, e.g index of a loop?

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I'm looping over an array, getting data from an API on each iteration.

I want to pass data from all iterations of the loop from my express server to the browser using `res.json()`, so I want to create an object that contains an object of data for each API call, as well as some other key-value pairs that will be created depending on what is returned.

e.g.
on loop index 0:

```
artist0: 
     {
        data: 'data',
        moreData: 'more-data'
     }
```

on loop index 1:

```
artist1: 
     {
        data: 'data',
        moreData: 'more-data'
     }
```

etc

I would use an array, but one of the calls (at random) will result in another key value pair,
e.g.:

```
correctAnswer: 'a_url.com'
```

this will be generated by one of the earlier API calls at random, so I cant get it at the other end using its array index.

I need the key 'correctAnswer', so I also need each object of API data to be identified by which API call it came from.

Short question: Can I name keys based on variables?

As always, your kind help is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Why? JSON can encode arrays just fine, just send the data as an array with correctly indexed elements, then unpack it browser-side to work with?

Comment: Yes, keys can be created however you want, using either `{ [someExpression]: someValue }` or by `anObject[someExpression] = someValue`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could solve this by not putting artists directly in the object, like this, using a array inside a single attribute of the object:

```json
{
    "artists": [
        {
            "data": "data",
            "moreData": "more-data"
        },
        {
            "data": "data",
            "moreData": "more-data"
        }
    ],
    "correctAnswer": 3
}
```

Or alternatively, if you really want a dynamic key you can use

```js
{
     [`artist${artistIndex}`]: {'data': 'data'}
}
```